# nodejs or expressjs is repeating calls to route when no response is returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using expressjs. My issue is that a route is called again if, for some reason, I do not provide a response. In firebug, status of the request will be "pending". Eventually, after the route is called a second time, I get back a response `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Here's a simple test:

```
// main.html
<html>
<body>
    <span>test</span>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $.get("/test");
</script>

// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log("I'm called");
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express started');
});
```

You'll see `I'm called` when you GET to the route, and then again after about 15-20 seconds.

It seems like Express or Node is somehow causing the route to run a second time. Why is this and how can it be prevented?

**EDIT**: Made a simple test demonstrating problem.

Comment: I've had my share of forgetting to add `res.send` in the route, and the browser never gets a response, yet I've never experienced this as far as I know, where the route runs twice. It sound more like something you did wrong in your app.

Comment: If `aModule.doSomething` throws, your `catch` handler will be executed. If it returns a promise that you don't care about (which you shouldn't, but well), `res.send(200)` will still be executed.

Comment: If you don't know whether the server or the browser issues the retries, you should check the http connection.

Comment: Just look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see whether the browser is resending the request or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, so it's not the browser. It must be something in Node or Express.

Comment: Edit: I updated my post to be more clear and added a simple example

Comment: You do realize that you're asking for trouble when you never create a response for the browser, right?  As you have it, the browser requests `"/test"` and your server NEVER responds to that request.  Is this still a problem if you just correct your code to always create a response?

Comment: @jfriend00 It's not a problem if I am able to return a response. But the problem is if some modules I'm using fails a callback or never returns a promise, and so my `catch` block will not trigger a `500 server error` response. In those rare cases, the route will repeat again. I guess I should wrap ALL modules I'm using in some promise block, regardless if they have their own or not? But why would Express/Node not send back `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` immediately after failing the first time?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting the repeat, but the real issue here is that your error handling is not robust enough to always return an appropriate response.  While it's reasonable to try to figure out why node is doing what it's doing, you should work on your error handling so that an appropriate response is always returned.  My guess is that you are hitting a server response timeout and then getting some sort of default behavior for that timeout.  See [here](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_response_settimeout_msecs_callback) for how to do your own timeout handling.

Comment: You're not ending the request, try `res.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be the solution for most people, but I'm working on a site built with create-react-app and I had the app open in two tabs.  For some reason, this was causing duplicate requests on the express side, even though I was only interacting with one tab.

Strange, but closing the second tab solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
// main.html
<html>
<body>
    <span>test</span>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $.get("/test");
</script>

// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send("I'm called"); // you have to res.send() method 
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express started');
});
```